# How to test React components that are connected withRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I have such a component

```js
const ButtonWithRouter = ({ to, history, ...restProps }) => (
  <Button
    onClick={() => history.push(to)}
    {...restProps}
  />
);
export default withRouter(ButtonWithRouter)
```

as you can see it uses react-router-dom and connected withRouter. 
My test looks like this

```js
test('render', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
    <Router>
      <ButtonWithRouter to='/anywhere'>Anywhere</ButtonWithRouter>
    </Router>
  );
    const tree = component.toJSON();

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
```

I don't think it's correct to import and use a real router into my test. How to do it correctly?

Comment: withRouter should already be tested by React Router, you should export the stateless component and just mock the props that you pass into it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing react component enclosed in withRouter (preferably using jest/enzyme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204828/testing-react-component-enclosed-in-withrouter-preferably-using-jest-enzyme)

Comment: @Win, my component requires to be wrapped into Router.
`Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`
 I don't know how to deal with that. Do you suggest mock?

Comment: If you can only have one export and your component has to be wrapped in Router, try using `proxyquire`. It's a library that allows you to mock imports. This way you can mock `Router` into a stateless component that returns its children only. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @Chris, is that possible to solve my problem by using just jest, without even enzyme?