# writing the unit test case for the container in the react js

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am writing the unit test cases for the react containers, which are using the connect function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/header.css';
import SignInInstruction from '../components/SingInInstruction';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUserJd } from '../actions/index';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import { logoutUser } from '../../login/actions/index';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { matchPath } from "react-router";
import { jdNameChange } from '../actions/index';
import history from '../../../history';


class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let job = '';
        const match = matchPath(props.history.location.pathname, {
            path: "/quiz-setup/:jobs",
            exact: true,
            strict: false
        });
        if (match && match.params.jobs) {
            job = match.params.jobs;
        }
        this.state = {
            job: job
        }
        this.imageClick = this.imageClick.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.job) {
            this.props.jdNameChange('', this.state.job);
        }
    }

    handleLogout = () => {
        this.props.logoutUser();
    }
    imageClick() {
        history.push('/');
    }


    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.jobs.length <= 0) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
                nextProps.fetchUserJd();
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <NavBar handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
                    imageClick={this.imageClick}
                    hasuserLogin={localStorage.getItem("access_token") !== null ? true : false}
                />
                <SignInInstruction
                    hasuserLogin={localStorage.getItem("access_token") !== null ? true : false}
                    disablejob={this.props.disablejob}
                    jobs={this.props.jobs}
                    selectedJd={this.props.selectedJd}
                    jdId={this.props.jdId} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        hasuserLogin: state.LoginReducer.hasUserLogIn,
        jobs: state.UserJobs.response,
        selectedJd: state.UserJobs.selectedJdName,
        jdId: state.UserJobs.jdId,
        disablejob : state.UserJobs.disablejob
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutUser, fetchUserJd, jdNameChange })(Header);
```

I have this container, Now I want to write the unit test case for this component.

```
import Header from './Header';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
const mockStore = configureStore();
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import SignInInstruction from '../components/SingInInstruction';



const storeFake = state => {
  return {
    default: jest.fn(),
    subscribe: jest.fn(),
    dispatch: jest.fn(),
    getState: () => state,
  };
};

describe('container <App />', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let component;
  let container;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();

    const store = storeFake({});

    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Header />
      </Provider>
    );

    container = wrapper.find(Header);
    component = container.find(NavBar);
  });

  it('should render both the container and the component ', () => {
    expect(container.length).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.length).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should map state to props', () => {
    const expectedPropKeys = [
      'hasuserLogin',
      'jobs',
      'selectedJd',
      'jdId',
      'disablejob'
    ];

    expect(Object.keys(component.props())).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(expectedPropKeys));
  });
});
```

So, But here it is giving errors like can not read property  props of undefined. So, I am not getting it how can I write this test cases ?

Comment: What is "it" that is giving you errors?  What specific errors are you receiving?  Have you dumped your props object to console to examine it?  What have you tried?  Which of your tests are failing? Based on your test code I suspect you aren't mocking the props the redux connect HOC provides, i.e. what you get from your `mapStateToProps` function.

Comment: Also noticed you aren't wrapping your component with your `withRouter` HOC either, so `props.history` is probably also undefined.

Comment: actually I am not understanding How can I write the test cases for this

Comment: Can you please give me some link or ant think from where I can write this

Comment: Try also exporting a "shallow" version of your header, i.e. just the header component itself, not wrapped in the redux and router HOCs, so you can pass a test props object directly to it.

Comment: The error that I am getting is expect(container.length).toBeTruthy();  is length is undefiend

Comment: @DrewReese It will be really helpful for  me if you give some idea or any answer  to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185462/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ganesh-kaspate).